# Unable to open github project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github

I'm new in github.I've cloned github repository to `D:\Documents\GitHub\Sneaker\`
Unfortunately when I do file->new->import project I got error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/D:/android_dev/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha1/gradle-3.0.0-alpha1.pom
    file:/D:/android_dev/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha1/gradle-3.0.0-alpha1.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha1/gradle-3.0.0-alpha1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha1/gradle-3.0.0-alpha1.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

What does it mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your gradle plugin?

Comment: I have gradle v3.3

Comment: Instead of cloning, can you import the project directly from File -> New Project ->Project from Version Control -> Github and see if it works?

Comment: tried - same thing